Applying scipy.minimize to Pandas dataframe with parameters
I have a function defined by f(x_0, x_1) = a(x_1 - x_0^2)^2 + (b - x_0)^2, where a and b are some parameters:
def f(x):
  return a*(x[1]-x[0]**2)**2+(b-x[0])**2

where x=np.array([x_0,x_1]) is a numpy array. Then the gradient and the Hessian of f are both easy to find and are given by
def f_der(x):
  return np.array([-4*a*x[0]*(x[1]-x[0]**2)-2*(b-x[0]), 2*a*(x[1]-x[0]**2)])

def f_hess(x):
  a_11 = 12*a*x[0]**2 - 4*a*x[1] + 2
  a_12 = -4*a*x[0]**2
  a_21 = -4*a*x[0]**2
  a_22 = 2*a
  return np.array([[a_11, a_12], [a_21, a_22]])

Now I have a Pandas dataframe df that records different values of a, b:
a   b
1   2
3   7
4  12

and I would like to create two new columns called x_0* and x_1* which are given by the values of x_0 and x_1 respectively, which minimizes f, subject to the constraints:
0 <= x_0 + ax_1 <= 1
0 <= ax_0 - x_1 <= b
0 <= x_0 <= 1
0 <= x_1 <= b

I know about the scipy optimize package and I can do it with one pair of a, b at a time:
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds
from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint

a = 1
b = 2

bounds = Bounds([0, 1], [a, b])
linear_constraint = LinearConstraint([[0, a], [a, -1]], [0, 0], [1, b])

res = minimize(f, np.array([0,0]), method='trust-constr',
               jac=f_der, hess=f_hess,
               constraints=linear_constraint,
               options={'verbose': 1}, bounds=bounds)

res.x

But my original dataframe is large (~100,000 rows) so I would like to ask if there is a quick way to apply the minimizer to the whole dataframe all at once and do it quickly. So the desired outcome looks like this:
a   b   x_0*       x_1*
1   2   1.00000001 0.99999999
3   7   1.12649598 0.4 
4  12   1.19393107 0.29411765


For a dataframe looking like
ab = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': (1, 3, 4),
    'b': (2, 7, 12),
})

x0 must be flat, and you need to pass in a and b as arguments.
The cost function to minimize must return a scalar, so return a simple .sum of your error vector.
Your definitions are not consistent. In one definition you show a lower bound of 0 and in another, a lower bound of 1. Since the lower bound of 0 is the only form for which a solution can be found, I use it. You also show inconsistent upper bounds - a or 1? I use a.
All together:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import Bounds, LinearConstraint, check_grad, minimize
import scipy.sparse as sp


def f(
    x: np.ndarray,  # (n*2)
    a: np.ndarray,  # n
    b: np.ndarray,  # n
) -> float:
    x0, x1 = x.reshape((2, -1))
    error = a*(x1 - x0**2)**2 + (b - x0)**2
    return error.sum()


def f_der(
    x: np.ndarray,  # (n*2)
    a: np.ndarray,  # n
    b: np.ndarray,  # n
) -> np.ndarray:
    x0, x1 = x.reshape((2, -1))
    return np.concatenate((
        -4*a*x0*(x1 - x0**2) - 2*(b - x0),  # derror/dx0
        2*a*(x1 - x0**2),                   # derror/dx1
    ))


def solve():
    problem = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': (1, 3,  4),
        'b': (2, 7, 12),
    })
    n = len(problem)
    a, b = problem.values.T
    args = a, b

    bounds = Bounds(
        lb=np.zeros(2*n),
        ub=np.concatenate((a, b)),
    )
    constraint = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.bmat([
            [sp.eye_array(n),  sp.diags(a)],      # 0 <= x_0 + ax_1 <= 1
            [sp.diags(a),     -sp.eye_array(n)],  # 0 <= ax_0 - x_1 <= b
        ]),
        lb=np.zeros(2*n),
        ub=np.concatenate((np.ones(n), b)),
    )
    x0 = np.concatenate((
        1/a/(a + 1),
        1/(a + 1),
    ))

    error = check_grad(f, f_der, (0.9, 0.7, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 1.1), *args)
    assert np.isclose(error, 0, rtol=0, atol=1e-6)

    result = minimize(
        fun=f, jac=f_der, x0=x0, args=args,
        bounds=bounds, constraints=constraint,
    )
    assert result.success, result.message

    problem[['x0', 'x1']] = result.x.reshape((2, -1)).T
    print(problem)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    solve()

These are the results:
   a   b        x0        x1
0  1   2  0.806485  0.193515
1  3   7  0.955379  0.014874
2  4  12  1.000000  0.000000

